# VS2013 crawling console apps

Tags: visual-studio-2013

One thing I would like to have is a console app that appears in the same position everytime I run the program from within the IDE. Quick fix anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically control the position of the console window:

In your class, put this code:

```
const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

private static IntPtr MyConsole = GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
```

And in your `static void Main(string[] args)` method:

```
int x = 10, y = 10;

SetWindowPos(MyConsole, 0, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: @KeithHarris Visual Studio should automatically tell you what namespaces are missing when you don't supply them